# How are you supposed to use set_rdbuf()?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, ifstream

So I am creating a class that inherits from ifstream, and that gives me acces to the protected function [set_rdbuf](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/set_rdbuf/), and at first I just thought it allowed you to set your own filebuf that then would be used, but that does not seem to work for me. I wrote the following code:

```cpp
class A : public std::fstream {
private:
    std::filebuf m_file_buf;

public:
    A() {
        if (!m_file_buf.open("test_file.txt", ios_base::out | ios_base::in)) {
            std::cout << "something went wrong";
        }
        // std::fstream::rdbuf()->swap(m_file_buf);
        std::fstream::set_rdbuf(&m_file_buf);
        std::cout << "m_ file buff is: " << m_file_buf.is_open() << "\n";
        std::cout << "rd file buff is: " << std::fstream::rdbuf()->is_open() << "\n";
        std::cout << "we are: " << std::fstream::is_open() << "\n";
    }
};
int main() {
    A a;

    return 0;
}
```

This will log:

```
m_ file buff is: 1
rd file buff is: 0
we are: 0
```

I was under the assumption that when I called rdbuf() I would then get the one I had set it to. However, if I use the swap function that rdbuf() provides, then it prints as I expect it to

```cpp
class A : public std::fstream {
private:
    std::filebuf* m_file_buf;

public:
    A() {
        m_file_buf = new std::filebuf();
        if (!m_file_buf->open("test_file.txt", ios_base::out | ios_base::in)) {
            std::cout << "something went wrong";
        }
        std::fstream::rdbuf()->swap(*m_file_buf);
        std::cout << "m_ file buff is: " << m_file_buf->is_open() << "\n";
        std::cout << "rd file buff is: " << std::fstream::rdbuf()->is_open() << "\n";
        std::cout << "we are: " << std::fstream::is_open() << "\n";
        // Get it back again as we swapped it out
        m_file_buf = std::fstream::rdbuf();
    }
};
int main() {
    A a;

    return 0;
}
```

```
m_ file buff is: 0
rd file buff is: 1
we are: 1
//and when I at the end swap back, everything is 1/open
```

I swited to pointer in the swap code so that I could point to the return of rdbuf()

This was compiled on MSVC version 19.28 with arg `/std:c++17`

So am I wrong is how set_rdbuf is supposed to be used, or is there something else I am doing wrong?

Comment: Documentation for `ifstream::rdbuf()` says: Returns a pointer to the internal `filebuf` object.

Notice however, that this is not necessarily the same as the currently associated stream buffer (returned by `ios::rdbuf`).
Make of that what you will. May I ask what is your use case that the standard library can't account for?

Comment: @EyalK. I am playing around with file locking https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-lockfileex With it I need a Windows Handle, and convert that handle to filebuf, that I want to use with fstream for the sake of simplicity. I have a working version using the swap function

Comment: Does the `permissions` function in `std::filesystem` not do the trick?

Comment: @EyalK. I don't think permissions locks the file. Looking for locking, like Atmoic locks/mutex except it is on a file and no other process can use that file while the process who locked it uses it. To prevent double write to a file from two seperate application